# how to create login page & new login acount creating?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, authentication, passwords

```
    try {
        Connection c = DB.getCon();
        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO login(LogID, UserName, Password) VALUES('"+jTextField1.getText()+"', '"+jTextField2.getText()+"', '"+jPasswordField1.getPassword()+"')");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    autoGen();
    clear();
```

I code this to my new login account creating form but the password is save like encrypted then i code login page like this it want do anything and there is no errors

```
    String user = jTextField1.getText();
    String pass = new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());

    try {
        ResultSet rs = DB.getCon().createStatement().executeQuery("select * from login where UserName='" + user + "' and Password = '" + pass + "'");
        if (rs.first()) {
            if (rs.first()) {
                Main_Page pat1 = new Main_Page();
                pat1.setVisible(true);
                Login_Page.this.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                jLabel6.setText("Login faild");

            }
        }`enter code here`
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

please anyone help me

Comment: what is your issue? what kind of error do you get?

Comment: when i create new account it's password is stored in database like encrypted code. i want to know how i use that encrypted code to login

Comment: i didn't get any errors. just not working.

Answer (score 0):

Examining the code you provided, one problem appears to be that you have redundant/nested if statements with no else clause on the outer if statement.  This would cause the behavior you described if the account was not found in the query. Try removing the outer if statement.